# Do I need a No Objection Certificate from my current employer to visit Berlin for a 3 day stay for an interview?

Tags: visas, germany, berlin

I am an Indian resident currently in Tokyo on work visa. I want to visit Berlin for 3-4 days for an interview. I have an invitation letter. As I understand, I need to apply for a Schengen visa. Will I have to ask my current employer for a No Objection Certificate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [official list of required documents](https://japan.diplo.de/ja-ja/service/tourist/903474) states only that you need a letter from your employer confirming the status of your employment. It does not have to say anything about your proposed travel, as an Indian NOC letter might. Such letters are not typically used outside India.

Answer (score 5):

The embassy replied - if the invitation letter states that my expense will be borne completely by the company I am interviewing for, then I do not need any further certificates.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting the embassy reaction.